# Animate button-view between specific coordinated

Tags: android, animation, coordinates

i want to animate a button in the orbit of several lines ...
For example i want to animate the button from a point A(0,0) to a point B(100,100) and then from B to C(200,0).
The problem is that the way i do this , between the A-->B and B-->C animations my view behaves  very strangely and it vibrates around the B location for no reason. Why is this happening ?

Also another problem is that when i animate the button for A to B the velocity in this route changes . How can i solve this ?

Here is my code :

```
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnticipateOvershootInterpolator;
import android.view.animation.TranslateAnimation;


public class LinearAnimation {
    public Animation fromAtoB(float fromX, float fromY, float toX, float toY, Animation.AnimationListener l, int speed){


        Animation fromAtoB = new TranslateAnimation(
                Animation.ABSOLUTE, //from xType
                fromX,
                Animation.ABSOLUTE, //to xType
                toX,
                Animation.ABSOLUTE, //from yType
                fromY,
                Animation.ABSOLUTE, //to yType
                toY
        );

        fromAtoB.setDuration(speed);
        fromAtoB.setInterpolator(new AnticipateOvershootInterpolator(1.0f));


        if(l != null)
            fromAtoB.setAnimationListener(l);
        return fromAtoB;
    }
}
```

and

```
  Animation.AnimationListener animL = new Animation.AnimationListener() {

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                btn.clearAnimation();
                /*rl=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(40,40);
                rl.leftMargin=DataBase.endX-(int)(btn.getWidth()/2);
                rl.topMargin=DataBase.endY-(int)(btn.getHeight()/2);
                btn.setLayoutParams(rl);*/
                if (DataBase.endX>=DataBase.Layout_Width+40)
                {
                    System.out.println("FINISHED");
                    btn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    stopLooping=true;
                }
                else
                {

                    setCoordinates();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            }
        };
        LinearAnimation anim = new LinearAnimation();
        System.out.println(DataBase.startX+"  "+ DataBase.startY+"  "+DataBase.endX+"  "+DataBase.endY+"  "+negative);
        Animation a = anim.fromAtoB(DataBase.startX, DataBase.startY, DataBase.endX, DataBase.endY, animL,5000);
        a.setFillAfter(false);
        btn.setAnimation(a);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `AnticipateOvershootInterpolator` on your animation.
Use `AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator` instead.